# Monstera Thai - Is it rust fungus? Thrips? Me being a hypochondriac?

Tags: pests, fungus, monstera

[image: Monstera Bumps under leaves with discoloration]

I got this beauty about 2 weeks ago and ever since she came home she has had those bumps under 3 of her leaves. This is the leaf that is the most affected. I have been googling day in and night and I cant figure out if its rust fungus, thrips or maybe it is totally normal and I am just freaking out for nothing. Ive never seen the above mentioned conditions in my life so I cant know for sure. I wasn't able to spot any bugs so far. The spots don't seem to be growing and there is nothing on the top of the leaves. Otherwise, the plant looks healthy and is growing new leaves.

Does anyone know what those bumps and discoloration are? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you done anything to the plant since you got it? My first thought was that the pH might be off. It could be a fungal infection and/or mites and/or edema. I'm not sure where the bumps are in the picture. I just see the dark spots.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to answer my own question for anyone that might have a Monstera in a similiar situation with similiar spots.

It was thrips. All of these markings are signs of damage from thrips on Monstera.

Hope this info will help prevent an infestation to whoever is in need!

Comment: You can mark your answer accepted. :)